# my linked list is returning just last entered node

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I'm doing a dictionary system for my school assignment. The idea that I'm trying to do is to store every single word and its definitions in a node and searching them using a binary search tree.

But there has an issue that occurred. When I add a word and definition in a node in the linked list, the wordList() method returns the last node that I've entered. I think I am having trouble implementing and linking the nodes. Could you please help me? (Note: Vocab is my test class)

```
public class Node {
    private static String word;
    private static String definition;
    private Node link;


    public Node() {
        link = null;
        word = null;    
    }
    public Node(String newWord) {
        setWord(newWord);
        link = null;
    }
    public Node(String newWord, Node linkValue) {
        setWord(newWord);
        link = linkValue;
    }
    public Node(String newWord, String newDefinition, Node linkValue) {
        setWord(newWord, newDefinition);
        link = linkValue;
    }
    public Node(String newWord, String newDefinition) {
        setWord(newWord, newDefinition);
        
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node [word=" + word + ", link=" + link + "]";
    }
    public static String getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }
    public void setDefinition(String definition) {
        this.definition = definition;
    }
    public static String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
    public void setWord(String word, String definition) {
        this.word = word;
        this.definition = definition;
    }
    public Node getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public void setLink(Node link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
}


    public class LinkedList {
    protected static Node first;
    private Node last;
    public LinkedList() {
        super();
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
    }

    public LinkedList(String wordName, String wordDefinition, Node first2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return(first == null);
    }
    public void insert(String newWord, String newDefinition) {
        if(isEmpty()) {
            first= last= new Node(newWord, newDefinition, first);
        }
        else {
            first = new Node(newWord, newDefinition, first);
        }
    }
    public void wordList() {
        Node current = first;
        while(current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.getWord());
            current = current.getLink();
        }
    }

    public static Node getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(Node first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public Node getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(Node last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

}

    public class Vocab {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList dictionary = new LinkedList();


        Node a = new Node("Assembly","A unit of fitted parts that naje yo a mechanism or machine, such as the headstock assemble of a lathe.");
        
        dictionary.setFirst(a);
        Node b = new Node("Boil","Agitation of a bath of metal caused by the liberation of a gas beneath its surface.");
        a.setLink(b);
        b.setLink(null);
    
        dictionary.wordList();
     
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the unused code from the question.

Comment: Indeed - this question contains over 350 lines of code, most of which isn't relevant to the questoin. Please provide a [mcve]. (In particular, it doesn't look like you need TreeNode or BinarySearchTree *at all*.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your `LinkedList`, use its methods rather than making the manipulations by hand:

LinkedList dictionary = new LinkedList();

```
    // Node a = new Node("Assembly","A unit of fitted parts that naje yo a mechanism or machine, such as the headstock assemble of a lathe.");
    
    dictionary.setFirst(a);
    //Node b = new Node("Boil","Agitation of a bath of metal caused by the liberation of a gas beneath its surface.");
    //a.setLink(b);
    //b.setLink(null);

    dictionary.wordList();
```

In the code above I have commented out all lines of code that go one level too deep. On the usage side you should never care that the `Node` class is used internally.

Have a look at LinkedList methods that will work for you. Then try to think of why when you are not using them you never alter the internal properties of the list, thus leaving it broken an half setup.

EDIT: By the way consider removing the `setFirst` and `setLast` methods that accept `Node` instances. They are only confusing you and should have never been there.